Running a GUI application within a native kernel-based Windows container?
I have some Windows applications I'd like to isolate from the system.
Using a VM is not an option due to the lack of GPU sharing (hardware acceleration is required).
I can see that Windows has support for kernel-level containerization and I am wondering if I can take advantage of that to install the target application within the container.
The challenge is that the target application is a graphical application (so I am looking to DIY some kind of Flatpak-like wrapper in Windows).
Is it possible to do this in Windows with Windows containers?
